# Flex Error #1014: Class flash.net::NetStreamPlayOptions

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a pure ActionScript project. I'm using Flex Builder on a Mac, Flex SDK 3.4 and I've even added the playerglobal.swc from the Flash folder to the project's library path. I get autocomplete when I add

```
import flash.net.NetStreamPlayOptions;
import flash.net.NetStreamPlayTransitions;
```

But when I run the movie, I get:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.net::NetStreamPlayOptions could not be found.
```

I don't get it.. What must I do to use those classes?

Comment: Similar issue.  I'm seeing this issue after building in the flvplayer component downloaded from adobe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the NetPlayStreamingOptions class isn't available In the Flex 3.4 SDK.  I changed my build target to Flex 4 (flash player 10) and it compiles fine.